# How do I stop the screen from jumping when clicking Accordion Menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a FAQ on my website but when pressing a question in the Accordion Menu the screen "jumps" so that the answer is on the top of the screen. How can I fix this?
I have tried to find and solve the problem but I can't figure out what's causing it.

You can see the *full* code here: https://codepen.io/Kxlly/pen/rNWEXqB

---

Here is the *summarized* code:

**HTML and CSS**

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:auto;
}

main {
  padding: 4% 10% 4% 10%;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

section h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.accordion-item {
  background: #070707;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 20px 19px 11px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
}

.accordion-link {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #070707;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

ion-icon {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.accordion-link .remove {
  display: none;
  scroll: none;
}

.answer {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.08);
  transition: max-height 650ms;
}

.answer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: .6rem;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #73D2DE;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.6)
}

.answer p {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
  max-height: 20rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link .add {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link .remove {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
      <body>
        <main>
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="accordion">

                        <div class="accordion-item" id="question1">
                            <a class="accordion-link" href="#question1">
                                Great question
                                <ion-icon name="add" class="add"></ion-icon>
                                <ion-icon name="remove" class="remove"></ion-icon>
                            </a>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <p>Great answer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="accordion-item" id="question2">
                            <a class="accordion-link" href="#question2">
                                 Great question
                                <ion-icon name="add" class="add"></ion-icon>
                                <ion-icon name="remove" class="remove"></ion-icon>
                            </a>
                            <div class="answer">
                               <p>Great answer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="accordion-item" id="question3">
                            <a class="accordion-link" href="#question3">
                                Great question
                                <ion-icon name="add" class="add"></ion-icon>
                                <ion-icon name="remove" class="remove"></ion-icon>
                            </a>
                            <div class="answer">
                               <p>Great answer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
          </section>
        </main>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a little bit of javascript for the functionality? Relying on `href` sand `id`s works technically but since you're jumping to the element with the specified id, you end up with that element on the top edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you’ve specified a reference to jump to in the href attribute of the clicked a element.

i.e. clicking an a element with a value of “#question-1 will force the page to jump to the element with an ID of “question-1”.

Considering using native HTML elements  and  for a simpler, accessible approach:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details